# Set a session in a foreach loop unique to each button

Tags: php

I have a results page that is generated using a foreach loop and session variables

This is what it looks like

```
<?php

  if(count($degree) > 0){
      foreach ($degree as $key => $val){
          $url = "http://www.concordiauniversity.com/".$val.'/'.$classname[$key];
          echo "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/classname_handler'><div class='control-group' align='center'><ul class='thumbnails'><a href=$url class='thumbnail'><img src=$url onerror=this.src='images.png' alt=Click the empty space here to see the class :) width=60 height=100></a><h4>$classname[$key]</h4><a href='/classname_handler' type='text' id='follower' name='follower' class='btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary' type='button'>follow class <i class='icon-hand-right icon-white'></i> $val <i class='icon-user icon-white'></i></a></ul></div></form>";
          $_SESSION['degree'] = $degree;
          $_SESSION['classname'] = $classname;
      }
  }
  ?>
```

My question is how to get the session set for each $classname so that when I click the follow class button the session is only for that particular class. The way I have it now, I get an array back.

Comment: Paste the output from `var_dump($classname);` please.

Comment: Have you started your session?

Comment: If you get an array back, you need something in the request that specifies which index of that array to use.

Comment: var_dump = Array ( [0] => chemistry 101 [1] => chemistry 235 [2] => chemistry 171 )

Comment: @jack That's what I am looking for, I can't figure out exactly how to do that. I  thought about doing another foreach loop in the classname_handler but I am still getting back the array.

Comment: You're not using `$key` anywhere, so that's probably what you would need; and you can write your session variables outside the loop, otherwise they're overwritten with the same contents every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure as to what you are trying to do here but from what I understand your session variable is getting overwritten with each iteration. Use something like

```
  $_SESSION['degree'] = $degree;

  foreach ($degree as $key => $val){
      $url = "http://www.concordiauniversity.com/".$val.'/'.$classname[$key];
      echo " ..... ";
  }
```

and then in the actual class page use the session to get your values back like

```
$_SESSION['degree'][KEY_FROM_URL]
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution I was looking for. it just took me a while to understand completely what I was doing!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multidimensional array inside the `$_SESSION`.

```
$_SESSION['degree'][] = $degree;
$_SESSION['classname'][] = $classname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was a combination of two answers

```
$_SESSION['degree'] = $val;
$_SESSION['classname'] = $classname[$key];
```

on the results page instead of the handler! Thanks!